# Highcharts - Pie inner circle size

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using Highcharts [Pie] series

How can I add **one more inner circle** with depth as it has marked in pic 1?

[`Online Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8bv0k1qe/)

> **Expected**:

[image]

> **What I am getting is:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: just change `innerSize : 150` it give your expected output.

Comment: Hi **@Harshad**, Actually I want to get one more circle inside as shown in pic 1. not to increase the inner radius. Sorry for that

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wafiqolazo/edit?html,js,output check this link for more you just add new series and change inner size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to have two series, each with type set to pie, then you can manipulate the look of the two pies with `inner size`.

Here is an example of your data with two pies, I made the `inner size` pretty wide so you can see what happens as you change it around.

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WLkJP/54/)

[image: example pie chart]

Good luck!

Comment: **@JordanHendrix**... Thank you so much... I got it almost right... Thanks for your time... I am **Accepting** and **Upvoting** your answer... http://jsfiddle.net/dj07u56o/